# What is the simplest method to POST a single on or off value (PHP)

Tags: php, post, checkbox, boolean

I have to pass either an ON or OFF value in php. Is a single checkbox to check whether a value is on or off the simplest method? I have:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="highlight">
```

and when it is posted, if it is checked I get the value 'on' but if it is not checked I get an error of 'Undefined index'

Now I have tried testing whether it is empty or isset but I would like to know if this is the correct method for passing a boolean value.

Comment: unchecked boxes are simply not sent in POST|GET

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question title to be more suitable

Comment: You could add stylized radio buttons where off or on is preselected like in modern mobile device settings. You can stylize the radio buttons using jquery or use jquery ui.

Comment: @Nitin thanks but I would just like the simplest PHP method

Comment: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE as this is asking for the simplest method. The above link is not what I am after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
 $cheeked = isset($_POST['highlight'])?1:0;
```

$cheeked will be 1 if checked and 0 if not.

Comment: Do you mean "checked"? That is interesting, I will use that, thankyou

Answer (score 3):

Unchecked boxes are simply not sent in POST|GET

You can just use the `isset()` function, its value is irrelevant:

```
if (isset($_POST['highlight'])) {
    echo 'it was checked';
} else {
    echo 'it was not checked';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is using a single checkbox the method you would use in this case scenario? Or is there a tailor made solution?

Comment: @gavin not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks, I was doing something similar, my problem was I was getting an error declaring the POST variable when it wasn't posted (ie it was 'off') so I am really just checking if it is set or not.

Comment: just if this is the simplest way to check if a single variable is ON or OFF (I thought I would be checking a boolean value or something)

Comment: some people like to do `$highlight=$_POST['highlight']; `... when there really is no need

Comment: `isset()` returns a boolean value

Comment: yes I was doing that first! Thanks

Comment: all that does is double the memory usage, the 'raw' POST array is fine to use